# Visual Studio 2022 Debugger JustInTime installation failure

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2022 Professional with the "ASP.NET and web development" workload to a Windows 10 machine. Install succeeded except for the warning "Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime.Msi".

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with nothing but the "Desktop development with C++" workload (and with both the Professional and Community editions of Visual Studio).

Answer (score -1):

I was running into the same problem and managed to fix it by:

1. Uninstalling Visual Studio 2022
2. Closing Visual Studio Installer and reopening it with administrator priviliges
3. Installing Visual Studio 2022 again with the desired workloads/components

Comment: I followed your steps and ran the installer as admin, but still wound up with the same error.